# Laravel Passport. Как авторизоваться по токену?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth2

Здравствуйте.

Использую laravel passport для авторизации. 
Для роутов использую middleware `auth:api`.

Задача: 
Авторизованным и неавторизованным пользователям нужно выводить список статей. 
Но если пользователь авторизован, то нужно еще выводить isLiked (лайкнул ли пользователь статью). 
Проблема в том, что данный middleware не дает доступа неавторизованным пользователям получать доступ к статьям. 
А если и вовсе убрать middleware, то я не могу получить доступ в объекту Auth (даже если передаю токен).

Как быть? Ручками авторизоваться по токену? И как можно так авторизоваться. 
Способы, идеи, мысли, буду благодарен за все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не использовать middleware для данного роута, проверять авторизацию в логике вывода данных, можно в трансформере или API Resourse

Answer (score 0):

Я не думаю, что тебе тут нужен паспорт, достаточно воспользоваться JWT, если ты видел пример как передается  csrf токен, ты можешь так же добавить к заголовкам `Authorization: Bearer <token>`, ну и написать Middleware для авторизации по JWT или воспользоваться кучей готовых библиотек, где уже это сделано. Например этот [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)